# Thread.Join never returns in FormClosing event if using Invoke method in worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, thread-safety, formclosing

I am writing an application using multithread. The application basically has a UI and a thread doing some work in the background and updating the UI. When I close the form, In the formclosing event, I notify the worker thread to stop. However, for some reasons It blocks and I have no ideas what caused it to block. Below is the simplified code of my problem, my actual code is more complicated.

```
namespace CmdTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Thread _workerThread;
        static object _lock;
        static bool _stopFlag;

        public Form1()
        {
            _lock = new object();
            _stopFlag = false;
            _workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadDoWork));

            InitializeComponent();

            _workerThread.Start();
        }

        delegate void UpdateUI();
        public void UpdateUICallback()
        {
            //Doing stupid things
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 10000)
            {
                i++;
            }
        }

        public void ThreadDoWork()
        {

            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                UpdateUI updateUI = new UpdateUI(UpdateUICallback);
                while (true)
                {
                    //telling the UI thread to update UI.
                    this.Invoke(updateUI);

                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                        if (_stopFlag)
                            return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }       

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            //tell the worker thread to terminate.
            lock (_lock)
            {
                _stopFlag = true;
                Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
            }

            while (!_workerThread.Join(0))
            { 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is if I use

```
lock (_lock)
{
   _stopFlag = true;
   Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
}
```

to stop the worker thread in a button event, the worker thread will stop but not in the form closing event. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why is your background task doing a bunch of non-UI work in the UI thread?

Comment: i was trying to simplify the code. My actual program does.

Comment: @stoney78us If it's doing work that takes very long then it's likely that you're mixing your business logic and your UI.  You should be pulling out everything that's not strictly UI related into work done in the background and then just displaying those results in the UI.  That UI manipulation ought to be quite quick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `FormClosing` event is waiting for the background thread to close before it lets the method end.  Note that it will be running in the UI thread.

Your background thread is, in a loop, invoking a method in the UI thread and, since you use `Invoke` rather than `BeginInvoke`, it is waiting for that method to complete before continuing.

The UI is running the closing event, sitting there doing nothing.  Since it's doing nothing, it can't process any of the other events in the message loop, including the one method that the background thread is waiting on.

Both threads are each waiting on each other, and no productive work is being done.  This is the definition of a deadlock.  It will sit that way forever.

Note that this is a race condition though; if you're lucky enough for the form to be closed after a given `Invoke` call completes and before the flag is next checked (which is hard; it spends very little time between those operations) then your program won't deadlock.

As for how to fix it; that's hard to say.  The whole example is somewhat contrived.

- Perhaps you don't need to be invoking to the UI at all from the background worker; if you're not actually doing UI work, you probably shouldn't be doing this.
- Do you really need to wait for the background worker to finish in your closing handler?  It's possible that you do, but often you wouldn't.

Comment: 1. In my UpdateUI() code, i actually do some UI update. I didnt want to post whole bunch of code so i wrote something descriptively.
2. Yeah, I want the application to safely exit.
3. before waiting for the worker thread to stop. the form closing set _stopFlag = true to enable worker thread to stop. I don't know how this could create a dead lock.

Comment: What i can understand from your comment is the Invoke method could not finish because it is waiting for FormClosing event to finish. However, the FormClosing event is stuck waiting for the background thread.

Comment: @stoney78us That is correct; they are both waiting for the other to finish, and they will both wait forever.

Comment: my quick fix is using BeginInvoke. However, this is not a perfect fix since the UI will close no matter what the UpdateUI() is doing.

Comment: @stoney78us Why is there a need for `UpdateUI` to continue working if the form is just going to be closed?  The user won't actually get a chance to see whatever's changing.

Comment: +1. yes, yet another join-generated deadlock in a GUI app.  For, like 25 years, it seems like I've been continually posting 'DO NOT WAIT IN GUI EVENT HANDLERS'.  'DO NOT INDULGE IN HARD LOCKS LIKE JOIN().  Some tutorials still suggest that thread termination must always be waited for with join().  Will someone please assassinate those authors before I go insane?